React Native NFC Scans occasionally returns undefined on iOS devices
I have a mobile application written in React Native which also uses Expo. It uses NFC scanning as a mechanism for placing stamps on loyalty cards digitally, so you can assume this is a very important functionality for me to work flawlessly. It works fine but one problem I have noticed is that sometimes when scanning on iOS devices, the plugin will return undefined even though a tag was scanned and a check appears in the iOS nfc drawer which pops up. I have tried debugging it using logs everywhere multiple and still found no cause for it happening, except that it happens randomly and when it happens, it tends to happen multiple times afterwards.
This is my code for starting the nfc manager in the app component:
useEffect(() => {
  const setupNfc = async () => {
    try {
      const isSupported = await NfcManager.isSupported();
      if (!isSupported) {
        console.warn("NFC is not supported on this device.");
        return;
      }

      const isEnabled = await NfcManager.isEnabled();
      if (!isEnabled) {
        console.warn("NFC is not enabled on this device.");
        return;
      }

      await NfcManager.start();

      if (Platform.OS === "android") {
        await NfcManager.registerTagEvent();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error starting NFC:", error);
    }
  };

  setupNfc();
}, []);

And this is my code for scanning an nfc tag:
const scanNFC = async (): Promise<string | undefined> => {
  try {
    await NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.Ndef);

    const tag = await NfcManager.getTag();

    if (!tag || !tag.id) {
      console.log("NFC: No tag found or tag ID undefined");
      return undefined;
    }

    const tagId = tag.id;
    console.log(`NFC: Tag ID found: ${tagId}`);

    return tagId;
  } catch (ex) {
    if (ex instanceof NfcError.UserCancel) {
      console.log("NFC: User canceled the NFC scan.");
    } else {
      console.error("NFC: NFC read error:", ex);
    }
    return undefined;
  } finally {
    await NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest();
  }
};

Here are some logs what would be helpful for you:
 LOG  NFC: Tag ID found: 0422DA34BA2A81
 LOG  HomePage: Tag: 0422DA34BA2A81
 LOG  HomePage: Scanned tag id is: 0422DA34BA2A81
 LOG  HomePage: Scanned tag belongs to an admin, skipping updating stamps...
 LOG  NFC: Tag ID found: 0422DA34BA2A81
 LOG  HomePage: Tag: 0422DA34BA2A81
 LOG  HomePage: Scanned tag id is: 0422DA34BA2A81
 LOG  HomePage: Scanned tag belongs to an admin, skipping updating stamps...
 LOG  NFC: Tag ID found: 0422DA34BA2A81
 LOG  HomePage: Tag: 0422DA34BA2A81
 LOG  HomePage: Scanned tag id is: 0422DA34BA2A81
 LOG  HomePage: Scanned tag belongs to an admin, skipping updating stamps...
 LOG  NFC: User canceled the NFC scan.
 LOG  HomePage: Tag: undefined
 LOG  HomePage: NFC scan did not return a valid tag

I'd be glad if any of you can help me with this!
